How to create NetworkManager profile for serial interface over SLIP protocol?
I've following network connection:
router <-> device Ethernet to serial (SLIP) <-> PC with serial input.
I need to reach network on PC over this chain.
I've attached slip interface over command line util:
sudo slattach -p slip -s 115200 -dL /dev/ttyUSB1 and as result I got unmanaged device as sl0.
How to create correct Network Manager profile for this purpose? I can't see any suitable interface type.
Please correct me if I goes wrong

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; not all products use network manager
